# .NET console output and PSExec

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, psexec

I'm running PSExec Microsoft tool with Process class executing a remote command with its own output like this:

```
            Process p = new Process();

            string args = @"\\remotemachine -u someuser -p somepass wmic product get name";

            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.Arguments = args;
            ps.FileName = psExecFileName;
            ps.UseShellExecute = false;
            ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ps.RedirectStandardError = true;

            p.StartInfo = ps;
            p.Start();

            StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;

            string output = output.ReadToEnd();
```

where *wmic product get name* is WMI tool running remotely with its own output listing all installed applications on the remote machine.
So, in the *output* I don't see the output of *wmic*, at the same time when I'm running PSExec in the command line locally, I can fully see the output of both PSExec and started remotely WMIC.
The question is, how can I capture all the output on the local machine? Should I run it in a separate console and try to attach to the console to capture all the output?

More generally, if put plainly, why is the output in the process *StandardOutput* and in the console when running PSExec directly not the same?

Comment: In case you were unaware wmic can connect to remote machines all by itself (/node)

Comment: Yes, but in my case I don't rely on the remote WMI since it has restrictions.

Comment: `ReadToEnd` will wait till the process exit. e.g. a `Console.ReadLine()` in the psExecFile could block your reading.

Comment: Probably. But, I see all in the command line. How can it block what is actually output in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

`ReadToEnd` will wait till the process exit. e.g. a `Console.ReadLine()` in the psExecFile could block your reading. But you can get the already written stream,

```
            StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;
            string line;
            while ((line = output.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Comment: `output.ReadLine()` is null when end of the input stream is reached.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, data written to both `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` is displayed in the console.

Within your program you need to look at each individually...try adding something like this at the end:

```
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```