# Why is Process.StandardOutput different from the actual output and/or incomplete?

Tags: c#, process, stdout, psexec

Well, first of all, when executing PsExec commands from C#, part of the output is in the `StandardOutput` and another part is in the `StandardError` *for some reason*, as mentioned [in other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26121677/4934172), but that's not big of a deal.

Now, the problem is: Even when combining the two parts together, the "output" isn't exactly the same compared to what gets displayed on the Command Prompt window. Sometimes it's different and sometimes it's incomplete.

**Here's my code:**

```
string args = $@"{computerName} -u ""{username}"" -p ""{password}"" {pathOrCommand}";
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo("PsExec.exe", args);
pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pi.UseShellExecute = false;
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pi.RedirectStandardError = true;
using (Process p = Process.Start(pi))
{
    var resultLines = new List<string>();
    var handler = new DataReceivedEventHandler(delegate (object o, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultLines.Add(e.Data);
    });
    p.ErrorDataReceived += handler;
    p.OutputDataReceived += handler;
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();

    p.WaitForExit();   
    string result = string.Join("\r\n", resultLines);
}
```

- **An example of when it's different:**

  When passing the wrong username or password, the following message will be displayed on Command Prompt: <sup>*</sup>

  > Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

  ..while the output of the above code will be:

  > The handle is invalid.
- **An example of when it's incomplete *(this is more important)*:**

  When executing this command `PsExec \\computer -u username -p password query session`, the result looks something like this: <sup>*</sup>

  ```
   SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
  >services                                    0  Disc
   console           someUserName              1  Active
   rdp-tcp                                 65537  Listen
  ```

  ..but the output when executing from C# is only:

  ```
   SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
  ```

**So, my questions are:**

- Why is `Process.StandardOutput` / `Process.StandardError` different from the actual output?
- Is there any way around this?

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>I'm only presenting the relevant part of the output here.</sub>

Comment: Maybe something related to the stream.AutoFlush settings?

Comment: @RubensFarias I didn't even use streams in my code. I used `DataReceivedEvent`s. Perhaps streams are used under the hood? Even if that's the case, would that cause the output to be a totally different English sentence? That's the weird part!

Comment: I understood that isn't a different sentence, but only a _truncated_/incomplete version; under the hood, we're playing with streams: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RubensFarias Have a look at the first example in my question: `An example of when it's different:`

Comment: I can't test a `query session` command now (IIRC the interactive mode or `psexec` ends when the remote process ends. There should be a switch to modify this a bit). About the error output, assign the `ErrorDataReceived` event it's own handler.

Comment: @Jimi I don't understand the first part of your comment. Assigning `ErrorDataReceived` to a separate event handler doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I haven't used `psexec(64)` in a while. IIRC, when not in interactive mode, the process exits as soon as the remote process exits. Getting a partial output is quite possible. But I never use `WaitForExit`. I set `.EnableRaisingEvents` and get the final output in the `Exited` event. I tested that command with a code +- like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312990/how-to-output-shell-command-to-a-richtextbox-in-visual-basic?answertab=active#tab-top), and I could catch the error output just fine (the same error you referred to: *Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password*).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why the output is different but I managed to create a workaround which I'm going to use unless someone provides a better solution.

I used `cmd.exe` to redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` to a temp file. After the process exits, I read the contents of the file and then delete it:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
string args = $@"/c PsExec.exe {computerName} -u ""{username}"" -p ""{password}"" {pathOrCommand}";
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"{args} 1> {tempFile} 2>&1");
pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
using (Process p = Process.Start(pi))
{
    p.WaitForExit();

    string result = File.ReadAllText(tempFile);
    File.Delete(tempFile);
}
```

Hope this could help someone else having the same problem.